# iOS Wifi SSID configuration displaying a subtitle in settings description cell

Tags: ios, settings, wifi, subtitle, ssid

Does anyone know how to configure a wifi connection in order to have the following description in the settings (a cell including a title and a subtitle).

[image]

Comment: Very likely requires a custom IE coming from the Wi-Fi AP, sniff the ibahn network beacons to see what they are sending…